# Does the Canon EF-S 18-55mm IS offer significant benefit over the Canon EF-S 18-55mm?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, image-stabilization, kit-lens

Does the Image Stability feature of the Canon EF-S 18-55mm IS make any difference compared to older non-IS version (Canon EF-S 18-55mm)? Which version is better?

Comment: I think the question should be edited slightly to make it clearer as to what you are asking.  You mean does the IS affect the Image Quality? Or just that you get sharper images by virtue of the IS?

Comment: I would like to know the overall benefit of using the IS version over non-IS version. Is it worth the extra money?

Comment: In that case - go with the IS version.  As the 18-55 is a slow lens, so having the IS will help you in low light and also general everyday use!

Answer (score 4):

Referred from [here](http://www.dpreview.com/lensreviews/canon_18-55_3p5-5p6_is_c16/)

**Changes compared to the non-IS versions**

1. The new IS lens is slightly longer than the NON IS (70mm vs 66mm)
2. The front element is larger in diameter (44mm vs 37mm)
3. The three elements after the front element are also larger, might be to accommodate the demands of the optical IS unit.
4. The aperture diaphragm has been moved and the lens coatings also seems to have been changed.
5. The lens remains impressively lightweight and compact 10g more than the non IS one.
6. The minimum focus distance has been reduced from 0.28m to 0.25m, which increases the maximum magnification from 0.28x to 0.34x.

Comment: I updated it...

Answer (score 3):

The IS version has an entirely new optical construction and is a lot better in every way.

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific as to what you consider *every way*. Currently, your answer looks more like an opinion comment than a proper answer containing any facts. Does *every way* also include price? Second-hand availability? [TDP review](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-18-55mm-f-3.5-5.6-IS-Lens-Review.aspx) seems to exclude flare resistance and vignetting at 18mm. I'd also expect a slightly higher failure rate from a more complex lens, but that's probably too early to say.